# Right amount of padding between buttons in a mobile app

Tags: gui-design, mobile, buttons, ios, tablet

I am designing a mobile app for both ipad and iphone. I have a navigation bar which has several buttons next to each other and an action bar that has several buttons next to each other. Is there a standard amount of space that should be between these 32x32 buttons so that the user doesn't accidentally have their thumb push the button next to it?

I can't find any data anywhere saying the right amount of padding there.

Comment: I have been looking on the web and found something. http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1085 Looks like Windows says 2mm or 8px.

Comment: Did you read through Apple's guidelines? http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

Answer (score 5):

Your interface sounds fairly busy.  Are you trying to take a pc interface and put it into a mobile or tablet version?  If so, you should consider rethinking the interface by designing it as if there were no pc version.

Comment: Only on the tablet would the action bar and navigation bar appear on the same page. We actually have limited the number of actions from the pc version to the mobile version. There are 3 action buttons on the navigation bar and right now 2 actions on the action toolbar. Just wanted to know how far apart these actions should be from each other.

Comment: You should take a look at the Apple HIG, or the Yahoo one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure.  I would produce some mock-ups and test it, along with looking at apps that are already out there.  Do some comparisons.

Here is a good list of guidelines for mobile and tablet.  I havent read them in depth:

http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/ui-guidelines-mobile-tablet-design